# Listing array elements in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to take input from the user and store it into an array, then use a for loop to list the items in the array. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[5], i, i1;

int main()
{
    printf("insert 5 integers");
    for(i=0, i<5, i++){
        scanf("%d\n", &a[i]);
    }
    for(i1=0, i<5, i++){
        printf("%d\n", &a[i1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So in the code, I get the following errors: "expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token" and "expected expression before ‘)’ token". I seem to get those errors very frequently when I try to code. Any help would be appreciated to get this code to work.

PS: A specific related question we are given is "how can you use a pointer to go through the elements of an array". I don't see how using pointers would help. Are they needed here?

**Update:** Thank you for your replies, I have changed the commas to semi-colons and have deleted the i1 variable. I also got rid of "\n" in scanf and "&" in the last printf as it would print the address rather than the value. Here is the now working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[5], i;

int main()
{
    printf("insert 5 integers\n");
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i=0; i<5; i++)` (use semicolons, not commas)

Comment: There's a logical error as well: Your second loop will not execute even if you get its syntax correct. Maybe you want `for(i1=0; i1<5; i1++)`. But there's no need of `i1` there. You could simply reuse `i`.

Comment: And remove the `\n` inside `scanf` if it was unintentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "expected ';' before ')' token" message is just the compiler telling you that you are missing semicolons in the for loop statement.

Your first for loop should be:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    scanf("%d\n", &a[i]);
}
```

Notice how the commas are replaced with semicolons.

In your second loop, you are iterating over the `i` variable, when you want to be iterating over the `i1` variable.  So, your second for loop should be:

```
for(i1=0; i1<5; i1++){
    printf("%d\n", a[i1]);
}
```

Notice how the `&` is omitted from the expression in the `printf`.  If you include the `&`, you will be printing out out the address (in memory) of the contents in the array.  You need the `&` when using `scanf` (in order to write to those contents in memory), but not when you are printing out the contents themselves.

As for the pointer case, well arrays and pointers are very much linked in C.  As a matter of fact, simply writing

```
printf("%d", *a);
```

will give you the first element of the array.  Arrays are pretty much short hand for pointer arithmetic.  So, you can think of `a` as a pointer to the start of the array (i.e. the element at index 0).  Then, `(a+1)` is just the element at index 1.  So, to print the element at say, index `i`, you just need to dereference the proper pointer:

```
printf("%d", *(a+i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use semicolons and you also should replace the line

```
 for(i1=0, i<5, i++){
    printf("%d\n", &a[i1]);
```

with

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){printf("%d\n", &a[i]);}
```

because you use i1 instead of i in the for loop

```
i1<0,i<5
```

makes no sense since you need to iterate after only one variable, i1 or i, or you can name it j or however you want but the variable inside the for loop should be the same for your iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `for loop` is wrong it should be  `for(i=0; i<5; i++)` same for the other one because the correct syntax for `for(;;)` that is why you got errors in your code 
it says 'token' and expected expression